# Using jQuery tabs to show hide additional content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

We use five tabs  in the centre column of our page which are used to show/hide content.

In our right-hand column, there is content that should only appear if tab one is selected (which is the default upon page load, named '#overview').

How can I ensure that when tabs 2, 3, 4 or 5 are selected, this right-hand div is set to display:none? Unfortunately, I can't include in within tab 1's content which would be thea easy solution - it must be displayed in the right column.

The class I want to hide is '`kis-widget`' (when #overview is selected) and our show/hide code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      if (window.location.hash)
      {
         show(window.location.hash);
      }
      else
      {
        show('#overview');
      }
    });

    function show(id)
    {
      $('#overview_div, #coursecontent_div, #profiles_div, #requirements_div, #fees_div').hide();
      $('#tabs li a').removeClass("selected");
      $(id + '_div').show();
      $(id + '_link').addClass("selected");
    }
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure that when tabs 2, 3, 4 or 5 are selected, this
>   right-hand div is set to display:none?

Along the lines of this:

```
DOM:
   TAB 1 .tab .tab-first 
   TAB 2 .tab 
   TAB 3 .tab
   TAB 4 .tab
   TAB 5 .tab
```

Code below:

```
function hiderighthanddiv(evt)
{
//whatever you want
}

function showrighthanddiv(evt)
{
//whatever you want
}

$('.tab').not('.tab-first').bind('click',hiderighthanddiv);

$('.tab-first').bind('click',showrighthanddiv);
```